# Tailwind CSS for Rails is not working in docker container but works in local properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, tailwind-css

I am trying to run my rails app in a docker container but Tailwind CSS is not reflected, even though the app runs properly in my local.
The app itself is running in the container.

Could anyone please give me some advice?
I would appreciate any help.

### Environment

Both are on development environment.

##### Local

- macOS Monterey v12.1
- ruby v3.0.1
- Rails v6.1.4.4
- tailwindcss-rails 2.0.8
- MySQL 8.0.28
- puma 5.5.2

##### Docker Container

- ruby v3.0.1
- Rails v6.1.4.4
- tailwindcss-rails 2.0.8
- MySQL 8.0.28
- puma 5.5.2
- nginx 1.21.6 <= using nginx only in the container

### Code

##### Dockerfile

```
# /Documents/project/my_app/src/postcss.config.js (in local)
# /var/www/my_app/postcss.config.js (in the container)

FROM ruby:3.0.1

ENV RAILS_ENV=development
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/my_app
WORKDIR /var/www/my_app
COPY /src/Gemfile /var/www/my_app/Gemfile
COPY /src/Gemfile.lock /var/www/my_app/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
RUN curl https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash
RUN curl https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs yarn
COPY . /var/www/my_app

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY /src/entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]

RUN bundle exec rails assets:precompile

# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

##### postcss.config.js

```js
# /Documents/project/my_app/src/postcss.config.js (in local)
# /var/www/my_app/postcss.config.js (in the container)

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require("tailwindcss")("./config/tailwind.config.js"),
    require("autoprefixer"),
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
    require('postcss-preset-env')({
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009'
      },
      stage: 3
    })
  ]
}

module.exports = environment
```

##### tailwind.config.js

```js
# /Documents/project/my_app/src/config/tailwind.config.js (in local)
# /var/www/my_app/config/tailwind.config.js (in the container)

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "../src/app/**/*.{html,js}",
    "../my_app/app/**/*.{html,js}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

##### docker-compose logs

There are some nginx errors actually, but I could not solve this issue.
I had no such errors when I deployed on AWS EC2 with Rails + nginx and the tailwindcss was fine then.

```sh
$ docker-compose logs

...
nginx    | 172.20.0.1 - - [21/May/2022:10:58:29 +0000] "GET /assets/tailwind.debug-bf571*******96d51.css HTTP/1.1" 404 188 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.64 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx    | 2022/05/21 10:58:29 [error] 8#8: *11 open() "/var/www/my_app/app/assets/inter-font.debug-f5972*******30f3fe.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost:80, request: "GET /assets/inter-font.debug-f5972*******30f3fe.css HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"
nginx    | 172.20.0.1 - - [21/May/2022:10:58:29 +0000] "GET /assets/inter-font.debug-f5972*******30f3fe.css HTTP/1.1" 404 188 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.64 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx    | 2022/05/21 10:58:29 [error] 8#8: *10 open() "/var/www/my_app/app/assets/application.debug-4f3e7*******4f55f.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost:80, request: "GET /assets/application.debug-4f3e7*******4f55f.css HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"
nginx    | 172.20.0.1 - - [21/May/2022:10:58:29 +0000] "GET /assets/application.debug-4f3e7*******4f55f.css HTTP/1.1" 404 188 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.64 Safari/537.36" "-"
...
```

### Others

I am sure that I run `rails tailwindcss:build` and `tailwind.css` are created in `/var/www/my_app/app/assets/builds`.

[update]
Here is my nginx setting.

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:////var/www/my_app/tmp/sockets/puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost:80;

  keepalive_timeout 0;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  client_max_body_size 4G;

  root /var/www/my_app/public;
  location ~ .*\.(swf|SWF|ico|ICO|jar|txt|gz|js) {
    root /var/www/my_app/public;
    expires 15m;
    break;
  }
  location ~ ^\/assets\/* {
    root /var/www/my_app/public;
    break;
  }
  location ~ ^/assets/|favicon.ico {
    root /var/www/my_app/app/assets/images;
    break;
  }
  location = /manifest.json {
    root /var/www/my_app/app/config;
    break;
  }
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    #auth_basic "Restricted";
    #auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    #if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
     #rewrite ^(.*) https://$server_name$1
      #break;
    #}
    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to add `root path_to_app_folder/my_app_folder/public;` to your NGINX config

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added my nginx setting and am guessing this is what you advised me. Unfortunately, the situation is not changing.

Comment: I think it should just be  put once into the server block. But as you added it least there, it is probably not the problem.. Not too sure what is wrong. Maybe watch the Docker logs and detect if no step is missed, like asset precompilation ..

Comment: Thank you, I am checking. Actually, the situation is changing so I am going to close this issue for now, and I will make another topic if I need to. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Adding a comment for future people that find this:
Worth taking a look at your Tailwind config files. I had this issue which was the result of adding a font to Tailwind which I had not installed in my Docker Image. No visible error, but the resulting image failed to load Tailwind and other tools.